# add a line to SPFile object

Tags: c#, file, sharepoint

I simply want to add a line to an SPFile object, which is a simple txt file.

Is there a simple way to do this ? I was thinking

Thanks

EDIT : that's what i have for the moment :

```
    public static void addLine(SPFile file, string line)
    {
        using(System.IO.StreamWriter strWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file.OpenBinaryStream())){
            strWriter.WriteLine(line);
        }

    }
```

I don't have any error here, but the file doesn't get saved. I've tried to do something like :

```
 file.SaveBinary( args )
```

But i don't know what to put in args.

If you can help me. 
Thanks

Comment: What do you have now that needs simplification? It's hard to judge what is simple and what is not without baseline...

Comment: Hey i've Edited my post. That's what i have for the moment. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: You are writing to read only stream which makes no sense. Approximate sample added to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [SPFile.OpenBinaryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470901), one of [SPFile.SaveBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms465421) to read/write. Some string manipulation of TextReader created over resulting stream like [TextReader.ReadToEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readtoend) and write resulting data to MemoryStream with TextWriter.

Warning: non-compiled code below:

```
using (var readStream = file.OpenBinaryStream())
{ 
  using(var reader = new StreamReader(readStream)
  {
    var allText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var writeStream = new MemoryStream();
    using(var writer = new TextWriter(writeStream))
    {
      writer.Write(allText);
      writer.Write(extraText);
    }
    file.SaveBinary(writeStream.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, i found a way to do it but i didn't use so much using, i guess your solution is better, because it closes the stream objects properly :).
Thanks for that